# UIBarButtonItem does not respond to action event

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am using a `UIToolBar` and have added a `UIBarButtonItem` to it. When I click the button it does nothing. It does not respond to action event. This is my code :

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, toolBarHeight)];
    [toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(changeText:)];
    toolBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barButtonDone,nil];
    barButtonDone.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `changeText:` method of this class isn't called when the "Done" button is tapped?

Comment: Nothing much wrong with that code. Check the functionality of `changeText:`, as @rmaddy suggests. Also make sure you are not also adding some other subview to `self.view` that covers the toolbar.

Comment: i first add picker and the toolbar above it and this is my changeText method : 
-(void)changeText:(id)sender {
    int tag = [sender tag];
    if(normalPicker) {
        [normalPicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else {
        [datePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    
}

Comment: @rmaddy yes it does not get called. Am i missing any line of code.

Comment: @DhruvJindal Your code is fine. Is there by any chance you have miss-spelling your action name "changeText"? put a nslog in your changeText method and see if it prints out. Also are there any warning when you compile your code?

Comment: the problem is when i press the button it does not get pressed. And yes spelling is correct and no, the method is not getting called.

Comment: @DhruvJindal Where is the toolbar being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if this helps. Again your code looks fine.

```
// create an array for the buttons
NSMutableArray* BarbuttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(changeText:)];

barButtonDone.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[BarbuttonsArray  addObject:barButtonDone];

[toolbar setItems:BarbuttonsArray  animated:YES];
```

I literally copied and pasted your code into a test project of mine and this is what I get. The only change I did was the method name

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(changeText)];
    toolBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barButtonDone,nil];
    barButtonDone.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];

}

-(IBAction) changeText
{
    NSLog(@"changeText ...");
}

2014-01-25 13:59:15.882 001-test-proj[15596:a0b] changeText ...
```

Comment: the problem is when i press the button, it does not go to a pressed state as you see when you press a button. I think that is the problem.

Comment: See my updated answer. If you copy and paste this exact and it doesn't work then there is something else going on in your project.

Comment: @DhruvJindal Well of course in iOS 7 pressed bar buttons do not, by default, look particularly pressed.